# No bean named 'org.sakaiproject.logic.SakaiProxy' is defined

Tags: java, spring-mvc, javabeans, sakai

I'm new to sakai development and i choose to use spring mvc. the tool is building fine but i'm getting No bean named 'org.sakaiproject.logic.SakaiProxy' is defined error

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/index.htm' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.sakaiproject.logic.SakaiProxy' while setting bean property 'sakaiProxy'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.sakaiproject.logic.SakaiProxy' is defined`

This is my `springapp-servlet.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
<!--<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />-->
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="10" />
   </bean>

<bean name="/index.htm"
    class="org.sakaiproject.tool.HelloWorldController">
    <property name="sakaiProxy" ref="org.sakaiproject.logic.SakaiProxy"/>
</bean>
```

and this is my `controller`

```
package org.sakaiproject.tool;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

import org.sakaiproject.logic.SakaiProxy;

public class HelloWorldController implements Controller {

/**
 * Hello World Controller
 * 
 * @author Mike Jennings (mike_jennings@unc.edu)
 * 
 */

private SakaiProxy sakaiProxy = null;

public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0,
        HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("currentSiteId", sakaiProxy.getCurrentSiteId());
    map.put("userDisplayName", sakaiProxy.getCurrentUserDisplayName());

    return new ModelAndView("index", map);
}

}
```

i don't know why this error is coming i google it out but not much help :(

Comment: i use sakai 2.8.2 and tomcat 5.5

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with

```
<property name="sakaiProxy" ref="org.sakaiproject.logic.SakaiProxy"/>
```

You're using `ref` attribute, which references to a bean by its `id`. There is no bean called `org.sakaiproject.logic.SakaiProxy`, hence the error. You probably want to create a bean called `SakaiProxy` and reference to it, i.e.

```
<bean id="SakaiProxy" class="org.sakaiproject.logic.SakaiProxy" />
...
<property name="sakaiProxy><ref bean="SakaiProxy" /></property>
```

For more info see [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators).

**EDIT:**

`sakaiProxy` is a `private` field. This may cause issues as normally spring injects beans via a `public` setter, i.e. `public void setSakaiProxy(SakaiProxy proxy)` *unless* the field is annotated with `@Autowired` (it can handle `private` fields too). For more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433143/why-doesnt-spring-support-direct-field-dependency-injection-except-for-autowir), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854428/spring-bean-fields-injection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536674/how-does-spring-autowired-work).

Comment: @DinkarThakur Are you sure that class `org.sakaiproject.logic.SakaiProxy` exists in your build path?

Comment: @DinkarThakur Please see the updated answer. If it doesn't help, I'll delete the whole answer.